# Read a list in the XSD to the list in OCaml and Coq

Tags: xsd, ocaml, coq

I have a matrix type is a list of vectors. And vector is a list of integers. It is in the XSD data structure. I want to know how the data structure read this constructor, is it they read from top to bottom or from bottom to top? more specified I want to know how this list look like in Coq and OCaml.
From my understanding:

I will have a list of list: `matrix = [[1 :: 0 :: nil] :: [0 :: 0 :: nil] :: nil]`

I just want to make sure my understanding. Could you please clarify it to me? Thank you very much.

```
 <matrix>
    <vector>
     <coefficient>
        <integer>1</integer>
      </coefficient>
      <coefficient>
        <integer>0</integer>
      </coefficient>
   <vector>
      <coefficient>
        <integer>0</integer>
      </coefficient>
      <coefficient>
        <integer>0</integer>
      </coefficient>
    </vector>
 </matrix>
```

Comment: You do realize that you ask a question with a context completely missing, essentially making it impossible to answer the question, unless someone accidentally knows the context? I mean, I am the author of matrix interpretations implementation in CoLoR and I hardly understood what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the CoLoR library, right? Did you look at its accompanying [Rainbow](http://color.inria.fr/rainbow.html) library? The conversion from XML proof format to a Coq .v specification happens there and you should be able to easily figure it out from the sources.